# How to update variables in a class from an activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have ImageAnalyzer class for image analysis using cameraX. I need to update variables in class from camera activity.

Code for camera activity:

```
class CustomCameraActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 
        viewBinding.currencyHistoryButton.setOnClickListener {
           val intent = Intent(context, CountryPickerActivity::class.java)
           startActivityForResult(intent, 112)
       }
    }


// Code to receive data from activity result which i need to pass to the class for updation

   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
       if (requestCode == 112) {
           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               val result = data?.getStringExtra("COUNTRY")
               Log.e(TAG, "COUNTRY:$result")
           }
           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
               // Write your code if there's no result
           }
       }
   }

}
```

code for imageAnalysis class:

```
class ImageAnalyzer(listener: ImageAnalyzerListener? = null) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer, ViewModel() {

    private val listeners = ArrayList<ImageAnalyzerListener>().apply { listener?.let { add(it) } }
    
    //value I need to update
    private val country = MutableLiveData<String>("Canada")


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageAnalyzer` class is a `ViewModel`, so assuming you have access to its instance, you would create another `read-only` live data and **observe** changes made to it.

```
class ImageAnalyzer(listener: ImageAnalyzerListener? = null) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer, ViewModel() {
    
        ...
    
        //value I need to update
        private val _country = MutableLiveData<String>("Canada")

        // only expose a readable state
        val country : LiveData<String> = _country
        
        fun updateCountry(newValue: String) {
            country.value = newValue
        }
    }
```

Then somewhere in your `CustomCameraActivity`, assuming you already have an instance of `ImageAnalyzer ViewModel`

```
fun someActivityFunction() {
    imageAnalysisVM.updateCountry("Thailand")
}
```

Now if you want to listen to its changes

```
fun listenToCountryChanges() {

    imageAnalysisVM.country.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            // react to changes made to the country
    }

}
```

Comment: I had implemented this but I wasn't able to observe new values inside the class.

Comment: So what is exactly is the question?,  you want to update the country? or you want to observe changes made to the country?

Comment: update and observe

Comment: i need to listen to changes inside that class only, and i guess i can not access viewLifecycleOwner inside that class, Thanks for the answers though.